# Range cells throws "RT ERROR 1004"

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to use a variables to define a range when trying to get a CoVar matrix of a few hundred stocks where I used the following code. However, the system throws a RT Error 1004.

```
Sub CoVar_Calc()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ArrA As Range
Dim ArrB As Range

i = 1
j = 1

For i = 1 To 487
    ArrA = Range(Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 2), Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 254))
    For j = 1 To 487
        ArrB = Range(Sheets(2).Cells(7 + j, 2), Sheets(2).Cells(7 + j, 254))

        Sheets(3).Cells(j + 1, i + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
        CoVar(ArrA, ArrB)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

When I run the first time using the following code

```
For i = 1 To 487
    Set ArrA = Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 2), Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 254))
For j = 1 To 487
    Set ArrB = Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(7 + j, 2), Sheets(2).Cells(7 + j, 254))

    Sheets(3).Cells(j + 1, i + 1) = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction. _
    CoVar(ArrA, ArrB)
Next j
Next i
```

things are all fine, but the second time I tried to run it it gave me the same RT 1004 ERROR message. I didn't do much change to the workbook within the two runs, but I did opened some other vba enabled workbooks.

Comment: All `Ranges` and `Cells` need to be qualified with their parent.  So, `ArrA = Range(Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 2), Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 254))` should be `ArrA = Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 2), Sheets(2).Cells(7 + i, 254))`.  This should also be done for the next.

Comment: Also I just saw you need to set all ranges; `Set ArrB = ...`

Comment: It can be simpler to use a "With... End With" block to make sure all the references match. Like this: `With Sheet2 : Set ArrA= .Range(.Cells(7 + i, 2), .Cells(7 + 1, 254)) : End With`